# What are the different equivalent systems of mathematical foundations?

Tags: foundations, type-theory

We've mostly learned that ZFC set theory can be used as the foundation of mathematics. I remember having seen that there are 5 or 6 equivalent frameworks that can provide the same theoretical foundation. It appears to me that Russell's Type theory and HoTT might be among them, but I haven't been able to locate the others.

Do you happen to know of a book that presents the various systems and explains the differences between them?

Comment: See W.S. Hatcher, [The Logical Foundations of Mathematics](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Logical_Foundations_of_Mathematics/wf3iBQAAQBAJ) quite old (no HoTT) but still useful.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to your remark "I haven't been able to locate the others":

An equivalent logical foundation for mathematics is provided by Internal Set Theory (IST).  This is discussed in detail in the monograph

> Kanovei, Vladimir; Reeken, Michael.  *Nonstandard analysis, axiomatically*. Springer Monographs in Mathematics. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2004. xvi+408 pp. ISBN: 3-540-22243-X

IST is only one of the systems considered in that book; see there for variants such as BST, RIST, HST, etc.